# csv output from SQL query

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I need to run SQL query saved in test.sql file from bash script. Bash script will be run from a linux server that is also running SQL*Plus which connect to database server.in addition, generated output of this query should be csv format and saved into linux server e,g /data/test.csv. Can somebody help me out?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus

Comment: @mustaccio that is a SO question, not a DBA.se

Answer (score 1):

wrapper.sql:

```
set echo off
set markup csv on
spool /data/test.csv
@/path/to/test.sql
spool off
exit
```

Command to invoke from script:

`sqlplus -S user/password@TNS @wrapper.sql`

Comment: I am getting an error SPOOL command not found, though i entered export ORACLE_HOME, export ORACLE_SID and export ORACLE_BIN values into the bash script

Comment: Regarding error SPOOL command not found, it sounds like you entered the spool as part of the shell script, not the sql script.  We can only guess because you don't show your code.

Comment: Worked. Thanks! Only thing i need to address now is to how to hide csv data from appearing on the screen.

Comment: I need to create directory with date stamp . Is there a command that can create a directory with current date in SQLplus?